# no software installed from terminal or software centre dpkg passwd error with reurn 1

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up passwd (1:4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package passwd (--configure):
 cannot compute MD5 hash for file '/etc/init/passwd.conf': failed to read (Input/output error)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 passwd
Error in function: 
Setting up passwd (1:4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package passwd (--configure):
 cannot compute MD5 hash for file '/etc/init/passwd.conf': failed to read (Input/output error)
dpkg returned error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what the full error is throwing, but it looks like a few settings are corrupted.
I suggest you run the following commands from the terminal:

- sudo apt-get remove software-center
- sudo apt-get purge software-center
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install software-center

This has worked for me in the past when an application has thrown errors, but I do not know the full reason behind your problem as the system details aren't listed... though they may not be needed.

As I reread through the error, it looks like the package is corrupt or the executed command has a syntax error, so if this does not work, purge the package cache and try installing it again, carefully checking the syntax of your command.